# Jquery filters array by multiple property and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have a multiple selectbox, and i try to get the filtered data based on the multpile propery selected 
LIKE THIS EXAMPLE

```
var names = [
    { name : "Joe", age:20, email: "joe@hotmail.com"},
    { name : "Mike", age:50, email: "mike@hotmail.com"},
    { name : "Joe", age:45, email: "mike@hotmail.com"}
   ];

var filteredNames = $(names).filter(function( idx ) {
    return names[idx].name === "Joe" && names[idx].age < 30;
});
```

But In my case, i want to filter by an array of values

```
 // data selected
var nameselected= $('select[name="usernames"]').val();
var ageselected= $('select[name="ages"]').val();
var filteredNames = $(names).filter(function( idx ) {
    return names[idx].name IN ( nameselected ) && names[idx].age IN (ageselected);
});
```

can i do that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter all the items that have names in `selectednames` array and ages in `selectedages` array you can do the foloowing:

```
var filteredNames = names.filter(function(item) {
  return nameselected.indexOf(item.name) > -1 && ageselected.indexOf(item.age) > -1;
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var names = [{
    name: "Joe",
    age: 20,
    email: "joe@hotmail.com"
  },
  {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 50,
    email: "mike@hotmail.com"
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 45,
    email: "mike@hotmail.com"
  }
];

//var nameselected= $('select[name="usernames"]').val();
//var ageselected= $('select[name="ages"]').val();

var nameselected = ["Joe", "John"];
var ageselected = [20, 45];

var filteredNames = names.filter(function(item) {
  return nameselected.indexOf(item.name) > -1 && ageselected.indexOf(item.age) > -1;
});

console.log(filteredNames);
```

**Note:**

- Note that you better use Javascript `Array`functions to loops over your array instead of using jQuery methods and complicating things.
- Note that this will only return items with ages in `selectedages`
  array, and not ages lower than `selectedages` values, in that case
  you need to sort the `array` of ages to check for the item that is
  lower than the lowest value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/indexOf) (value of result >-1 if value is inside an array ) to check if your data value is inside your array of selected value

See beloow Snippet :

```js
var names = [
    { name : "Joe", age:20, email: "joe@hotmail.com"},
    { name : "Mike", age:50, email: "mike@hotmail.com"},
    { name : "Joe", age:45, email: "mike@hotmail.com"},
    { name : "Doe", age:40, email: "doe@hotmail.com"}
   ];

var nameselected = ["Joe","Doe"];
var ageselected =  [20,40,35];

var filteredNames = $(names).filter(function( idx ) {
    return (nameselected.indexOf(names[idx].name)>-1 && ageselected.indexOf(names[idx].age)>-1);
}); 

$.each(filteredNames,function(index,name){
  console.log(name);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```